# Best way to store image file in postgres db using typeorm

Tags: postgresql, image, typeorm

I trying to figure the best way to store an image in a database using typeorm.  Should you store it as a data url or as a buffer?  Currently it would be over kill for my application to store it in a CDN hence the reason I want to store it in the db.

My thought was to save it as a data url as well as a field for the image name.

Appreciate any into!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends much on your production infrastructure. By the way, IMHO the best way would consist in storing at least the file path where the content gets uploaded to (local, bucket, etc..) and the file's mimetype.